# What is the domain of: $f(x,y)=\ln{\frac{6-2x-3y+xy}{4-x-y}}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

What is the domain of:

$$f(x,y)=\ln{\frac{6-2x-3y+xy}{4-x-y}}$$

What I tried:

$6-2x-3y+xy<0$ and $4-x-y<0$

or

$6-2x-3y+xy>0$ and $4-x-y>0$

The thing is that I need to then draw the whole domain, but I don't get it how to do that and transform this equations into a more favorable form

Comment: Hint: $6 - 2x - 3y + xy = (x-3)(y - 2)$ and $4 - x - y = 0$ is the line.

Comment: @IPPK what is the process of getting to that form

Comment: @BiliDebili $6-2x-3y+xy=-2(x-3)+y(x-3)=(x-3)(y-2)$